# Firebase AppCheck is rejecting calls from web app

Tags: javascript, firebase-app-check

I have a web app that's designed to run on localhost to manage my data on Firestore.
My firebase project has AppCheck enabled, and because of that all of my calls to firebase are rejected, despite registering reCAPTCHA.

My question is whether it is possible to register reCAPTCHA where 'localhost' is my domain, and whether my implementation is correct:

**My implementation:**

```html
<html lang="en">
....
<body>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXX" data-badge="inline" data-size="invisible" data-callback="onSubmit">
</div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</body>
....
</html>
```